# How do I pass a bind value in angular function controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am a newbie in angularjs and needs to pass a model bind value in a function which is declared in controller but when I accesss that value from controller it says undefined. Below is the code

HTML:

```
<div>
        <p g-bind-template>{{model.myname}}</p>
        <div>
          <div data-ng-controller="formCtrl" data-ng-init="init(model.myname)"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In the above HTML when i do {{model.myname}} I can see the value but how to pass it in init method.

In Controller I have wrote a function

```
$scope.init = function (myname) {
      alert(myname) // displays undefined
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paragraph tag should be within the `ng-controller` in html. Make it like this:

```
<div>    
    <div>
      <div data-ng-controller="formCtrl" data-ng-init="init(model.myname)">
        <p g-bind-template>{{model.myname}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still says undefined

Comment: how can I pass model.myname in init function

Comment: Why would you want to pass a scope variable if its already present in controller? You can directly access `$scope.model.myname`

Comment: I have tried it before and again I have tried it it still says undefined

Comment: Actually I want to pass this value to a controller function to fetch the records from database and show it in dropdown. By $scope.model.myname is displaying undefined